# GestureOverlayView can't be used in homescreen?

Tags: android, widget

My goal is to create a widget that has a GestureOverlayView which allows me to read gestures, and match them to a library of saved gesture patterns, to determine a specific action.

When I add this widget to my homescreen I get "Problem loading widget"

I then found this part of the documentation:

"While widgets could be understood as "mini apps", there are certain limitations that are important to understand before you start to embark on designing your widget:

Gestures

Because widgets live on the home screen, they have to co-exist with the navigation that is established there. This limits the gesture support that is available in a widget compared to a full-screen app. While apps for example may support a view pager that allows the user to navigate between screens laterally, that gesture is already taken on the home screen for the purpose of navigating between home panels.

So does this mean I cannot use this view as a widget to my homescreen?